# net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID using netty's WebSocket

Tags: netty, wss

I have a WSS server with certification. A HTTPS web client is trying to connect my WSS server in order to receive data through this socket. Client gets ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, no exception in netty's handlers.
The server is pretty much like the nettty WSS example, with a little change - I'm not using the SelfSignedCertificate since I need to use my own certification.
This is the code of the Server bootstrap:

```
    private ServerBootstrap b;
private EventLoopGroup bossGroup;
private EventLoopGroup workerGroup;
final SslContext sslCtx;

public NettyWebSocketServer(ServerProperties srvProp, ConcurrentExecutor executor) {
    super(srvProp, executor);
    bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
```

//        setExecutorService(workerGroup);

```
    try {
        if (srvProp.isSsl()) {
            File privateKeyFile = new File("/home/ec2-user/webup/myKey.key");

            File certificateFile = new File("/home/ec2-user/webup/myCert.crt");
            if (privateKeyFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("private Key File created: " + FileUtil.getFileContent(privateKeyFile));
            }
            if (certificateFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("certificate File created: " + FileUtil.getFileContent(certificateFile));
            }
            sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(certificateFile, privateKeyFile).build();
            if (sslCtx != null) {
                System.out.println("SSL context created! isServer=" + sslCtx.isServer());
            }
        } else {
            sslCtx = null;
        }
        b = new ServerBootstrap();

        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(srvProp.isSsl() ?
                        new WssServerInitializer(this, sslCtx) : new WebSocketServerInitializer(this))
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
    } catch (SSLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void start() throws InterruptedException {

    try {
        Channel ch = b.bind(/*srvProp.getAddress(),*/ srvProp.getPort()).sync().channel();
        localAddress = ((InetSocketAddress) ch.localAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();
        Log.write("Open your web browser and navigate to " +
                (getServerProperties().isSsl() ? "https" : "http") + "://" + srvProp.getAddress() + ":" + srvProp.getPort() + '/');
        System.out.println("\nNettyWebSocketServer started on " + srvProp.getServerShortInfo() + '\n');
        ch.closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }

}
```

Comment: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`, this happens when the domain name inside the certificate file is differend from the domain name the client is trying to connect to, can you post both domain names?

Comment: But those key file and cert file are working   \

Comment: If you get to this point during setup, they keys are working. But there is still 1 part in he SSL communications that is blocking you. SSL certificates are domain name sensitive. You cannot get an ssl certificate for `example.com` and expect it to work for `google.com`. Likewise an certificate for `example.com` won't work for `localhost`. I'm asking you to provide the names stored inside the certificate file (like `example.com`)  and the domain name you are trying to connect with (like `localhost`). If hey don't match, you get the unavoidable error `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: @Ferrybig One year later, here I am, and willing to join the club. Okay, I'm facing the same problem. I'm using this `wss://my_ip:443`, and in my websocket_server.php, the port 8080. The error shown in my browser console is that one: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. Which part of my certificates should I alter to make the domains in each of them the same?